# How to get static "data" information from all route items present in my menu (including lazy-loading)?

Tags: angular

I have an ordinary Angular app.
Each component's routing module in my menu has custom information in static "data" property:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: GlobalDefinitionsComponent,
    data: { moduleId: 'CTGLOBALDEF', requiredPolicy: 'MyTools.GlobalDefinitions.Read'},
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to get "moduleId" for my whole menu tree (including lazy-loading nodes), not just for current activated route. I can't believe it is not possible - indeed, a whole menu structure is predefined, so each element's data has to be accessible somehow. However, I have not found such information.
The "moduleId" value eventually determines if the page bound to the given route needs to be displayed or hidden in the navigation menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to resolve it.

First of all - it is not possible to "look ahead" and filter out lazy-loading nodes. Instead, it is required to "duplicate" the sought data from the lazy-loading routing module which matches the parent item's route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CompaniesComponent,
    data: { moduleId: 'CTComp', requiredPolicy: 'Companies.Read' },
  },
  ...
]
```

into `route.provider.ts` using `as any` for "suspend type checking":

```
  {
    path: '/companies',
    data: { moduleId: 'CTComp' },
    name: '::Menu:Companies',
    requiredPolicy: 'Companies.Read',
    parentName: '::Menu:General',
    order: 1
  } as any,
```

After that the custom data is accessible as `(nonLazyRouteItem as any).data?.moduleId`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have access to routes:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const routes = this.router.config; // do any you need with routes data
}
```

Comment: The config does not return lazy-loading children nodes (`loadChildren: () => import('./applications/applications.module').then(m => m.ApplicationsModule)`) alas - only ordinary nodes.